# Creating various records for User with nested resources from new action error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-resources

I have a model `User` and `StockShipment`.

I'm trying to create various StockShipments for my user from the StockShipment `new` action.

*For this, I use in my User model:*

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :stock_shipments, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

**In my stockshipments/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with model:  [@user, @stock_shipment] do |form| %>
             <%= form.fields_for :stock_shipments, @user.stock_shipments.build do |shipment_form| %>
                <%= render 'shared/shipment_fields', form: shipment_form, locals: { user: current_user, user_stock: @user_stock } %>
              <% end %>
```

**In my Stock Shipments controller:**

```
  def new
    @user = current_user
    @stock_shipment = StockShipment.new
    @user.stock_shipments.build 
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @user_stock = UserStock.find(params[:stock_shipment][:user_stock_id])
    @stock_shipment = @user.stock_shipments.build(stock_shipments_params)

    if @stock_shipment.save
      ShipmentNotificationMailer.new_shipment_notification(@stock_shipment).deliver_later
      redirect_to user_stock_shipments_path(current_user), status: :see_other
    else
      puts @stock_shipment.errors.full_messages.inspect
    end
  end
```

**Lastly, I have my strong parameters to accept nested attributes:**

```
def stock_shipments_params
  params.require(:stock_shipment).permit(
    :country, :phone, :email,
    :name, :quantity, :address, :city, :province, :postalcode, :surname, :user_id, :campaign_id, :gift_selection_id, :delivery_date, :stock_variation, :description, :user_stock_id,
    stock_shipments_attributes: [:id, :country, :phone, :email, :name, :quantity, :address, :city, :province, :postalcode, :surname, :user_id, :campaign_id, :gift_selection_id, :delivery_date, :stock_variation, :description, :user_stock_id, :_destroy]
  )
end
```

*I'm getting the following error all the time:*

```
Unpermitted parameter: :stock_shipments.
```

My params being passed:

```
Started POST "/users/388/stock_shipments?locale=es" for ::1 at 2023-12-17 13:58:03 +0100
13:58:03 web.1    | Processing by StockShipmentsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
13:58:03 web.1    |   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "stock_shipment"=>{"stock_shipments"=>{"quantity"=>"1", "name"=>"asdf", "surname"=>"asdf", "address"=>"sadf", "postalcode"=>"213", "city"=>"asdf", "province"=>"asdf", "country"=>"bg", "phone"=>"234", "email"=>"asd@asdf.com", "delivery_date"=>"2023-12-20", "user_id"=>"388", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "user_stock_id"=>"84", "user_id"=>"388"}, "user"=>{"stock_shipments_attributes"=>{"1702817879"=>{"quantity"=>"30", "name"=>"María", "surname"=>"Jisd", "address"=>"Cadsf", "postalcode"=>"238", "city"=>"Madrid", "province"=>"adsf", "country"=>"es", "phone"=>"645455555", "email"=>"adsf@adsf.com", "delivery_date"=>"2023-12-20", "user_id"=>"388", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Confirmar envíos", "locale"=>"es", "user_id"=>"388"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing the partial, which is where some of the issue is going to be, but you're sending `user_stock: @user_stock` into it and yet `@user_stock` isn't defined anywhere.

Mostly though, you've just got a lot of unnecessary junk in your `form_with` and `fields_for` calls. You should be following [the nested form guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms) for fun and profit.

Comment: Hello @smathy, thanks for your help. Do you think the issue is related that I'm creating a nested resource from the same model? I'm creating User Stock Shipments from my stock_shipment#new instead of a Users view and that is redundant to Rails?

Comment: No, the view helpers don't care about which controller you're using, only which arguments you're passing in.